# Multi-dimensional documents with Gensim

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, gensim, tf-idf

I'm working on a document comparison engine / search engine. I'm currently using it as follows...

```
search_doc = ["test search"]
documents = ["doc 1 text", "doc 2 text", "doc 3 text", "..."]
```

And then comparing the results.

What I would like to do (in the simplest terms possible) is have multi-dimensional documents (a document that has multiple dimensions, rather than just the "document")... for example..

```
documents = {
                { "doc 1 title", "doc 1 body", "doc 1 tags" },
                { "doc 2 title", "doc 2 body", "doc 2 tags" },
                { "doc 3 title", "doc 3 body", "doc 3 tags" }
                { ... }
            }
```

And also be able to weight the results (for example, title is 0.6, body is 0.4, etc).

My question is... is there a way to do this within Gensim, or do I need to create a separate document for each meta item of the document (for example, comparing to each meta item (title, body, tags) as a separate document, and then combining weights after the fact using the document key/id?

I'm not sure i'm doing a good job of explaining this, but please let me know if I can improve my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim's major algorithms (like LDA or Doc2Vec) are trained from distinct individual documents, with no idea about sub-fields or composable sub-parts. So you'll have to model that yourself.

You should create a separate document per field, if your end-goals require the separate scoring per field.

You may also still want to create a full document composed of all fields.

You then might train a model on all full-docs and fields combined, or a separate model per type-of-doc.

How you might want to compare, deduplicate, or combine the scores of fields versus documents would be very dependent on your data and project goals, and your own experiments and custom evaluations. (For example, perhaps your users are most satisfied with body-matches, so any similarities in that field should have extra weight in your display – and so forth.)

Comment: Thank you! That is generally what I expected, I very much appreciate the clarity on the topic!